# Bind videos from folder in asp.net using datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlVideos" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <video controls="controls"  width="200" height="200" src='<%# Eval ("Name","videos/{0}") %>'>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

public partial class videos : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDataList();
        }
    }
    protected void BindDataList()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/videos"));
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
        foreach (FileInfo info in files)
        {
            listItems.Add(info);
        }
        dtlVideos.DataSource = listItems;
        dtlVideos .DataBind(); 
    }
}
```

unable to play videos in chrome  or browsers and mozilla is only supporting in .mp4 format not other formats 
i want to make this app support all formats

Answer (score 0):

```
<video controls="controls"  width="200" height="200" src='<%# Eval ("Name","videos/{0}") %>'>"/>
```

Thil line should be

```
<video controls="controls"  width="200" height="200" src='<%# Eval ("Name","videos/{0}") %>'></video>
```

or

```
<video controls="controls"  width="200" height="200" src='<%# Eval ("Name","videos/{0}") %>'/>
```

---

[Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

To make an HTML5 video, which works in the newest versions of all major browsers, you can serve your video in both WebM format and MPEG H.264 AAC format, using the [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) element like this:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.
  <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browsers -->
</video>
```

Comment: i have latest browsers just want to know why this video is not able to run on chrome

Comment: do you have any   solution to play it on chrome , Ie & Opera @Nagaraj

Comment: @user3201772 Be frank i does not have any solution for your question